# Concatenating sliced strings based on slice indices in csv file

Tags: python, csv

Well, my challenge seems easy but I am run out of options. So any help will be appreciated.

I have many DNA sequences in fasta format and they need to be sliced at particular positions and then concatenate the resulting parts. So if my sequence file is like so:

```
~$ cat seq_file
>Sequence1
This is now a sequence that must require a bit of slicing and concatenation to be useful
>Sequence2
I have many more uncleaned strings like this in the form of sequences
```

I want the output to be so:

```
>Sequence1
This is useful
>Sequence2
I have cleaned sequences
```

Now the slice portions are determined by the slice indices from a separate csv file. In this case slices positions are organized as this:

```
~$ cat test.csv
Sequence1,0,9,66,74,,
Sequence2,0,5,15,22,48,57
```

My code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv

seq_dict = {}
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse('seq_file', 'fasta'):
    descr = seq_record.description
    seq_dict[descr] = seq_record.seq

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        seq_id = row[0] 
        for n in range(1,7): 
            if n % 2 != 0:
                start = row[n] # all start positions for the slice occupy non-even rows
            else:
                end = row[n] 

                for key, value in sorted(seq_dict.iteritems()):
                    #print key, value
                    if key == string_id: # cross check matching sequence identities
                        try:
                            slice_seq = value[int(start):int(end)]
                            print key
                            print slice_seq
                        except ValueError:
                            print 'Ignore empty slice indices.. '
```

Now this would print:

```
Sequence1
Thisisnow
Sequence1
useful
Ignore empty slice indices.. 
Sequence2
Ihave
Sequence2
cleaned
Sequence2
sequences
```

So far so good, this is what I expected. But how do I bring sliced portions together by concatenation or joining or by whatever operation possible within python to my desired end? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that with a couple of modifications:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        seq_id = row[0]
        seqs = []
        for n in range(1,7):
            if n % 2 != 0:
                start = row[n] # all start positions for the slice occupy non-even rows
            else:
                end = row[n]

                for key, value in sorted(seq_dict.iteritems()):
                    #print key, value
                    if key == seq_id: # cross check matching sequence identities
                        try:
                            seqs.append(value[int(start):int(end)])
                        except ValueError:
                            print 'Ignore empty slice indices.. '
        print ' '.join(str(x) for x in seqs)
```

Comment: I used `str(x)` to make strings out of the `Seq` objects, because `join` cannot work with them.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
import csv
from string import whitespace
with open('seq_file') as f1, open('test.csv')  as f2:
    for row in csv.reader(f2):
        it = iter(map(int, filter(None, row[1:])))
        slices = [slice(*(x,next(it))) for x in it]
        seq = next(f1)
        line = next(f1).translate(None, whitespace)
        print seq,
        print ' '.join(line[s] for s in slices)
```

**Output:**

```
>Sequence1
Thisisnow useful
>Sequence2
Ihave cleaned sequences
```

Comment: Great. This place is amazing.